# N^2 diagram explanation

Tags: openmdao

The N^2 diagram is color and shape coded.

Are the explanations of these included in the manual somewhere?

Some of them can be deduced more easily for example I assume orange one is implicit comp output. But there are combinations of black, gray circle square and surrounded square

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get some information, you can click on the 'Show legend' button (the sixth button starting from the right as for OpenMDAO 2.2.1). The legend is displayed at the bottom.